# Integrate Google closure compiler with Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, minify, google-closure-compiler

Does anybody know how to integrate [Google closure compiler](http://code.google.com/intl/sr-RS/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app.html) with Eclipse IDE? The thing I was trying to do is to configure Google closure compiler as a external tool for Eclipse IDE. Then I would be able to run closure compiler within IDE and minify my Javascript files with single click.
Have anybody solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>Rock Star Apps provide a little-known plugin which does this. I just wrote a blog article on it: [removed as doesn't exist anymore].</strike>

After some googling, I also found this, but haven't tested it: https://github.com/greggian/Eclipse-Closure-Compiler.

Update: the Rock Star Apps site no longer works. Were I to try to do this today, I would definitely just download the [closure compiler jar](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), write an ant script to run it (something like the code below), and then create a project builder for it.

```
<target name="rebuild">

    <taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask"
            classpath="/opt/closure-compiler/compiler.jar"/>

    <jscomp compilationLevel="simple" warning="quiet" 
        debug="false" output="js/all.closure.js">
        <sources dir="js">
            <file name="script1.js"/>
            <file name="script2.js"/>
            <file name="script3.js"/>
            <file name="script4.js"/>
            <file name="script5.js"/>
            <file name="script6.js"/>
        </sources>
    </jscomp>

</target>
```

Comment: too bad for the hijacked domain :(

Comment: Rock Star Apps can't be found anymore because of the hijacked domain, but you can still manually download and install the zip. I just followed this post instructions and it worked: http://blog.avirtualhome.com/rockstarapps-for-eclipse/

Comment: You should update your post properly to remove the bad URL. It now hosts a site trying to trick people into downloading suspicious "FlashPlayer" updates...

Answer (score 4):

you could use ant tasks for this
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/BuildingWithAnt

Answer (score 4):

try these eclipse plugins:

Eclipse Plugin for Closure Templates

Eclipse Plugin for JavaScript with Closure Compiler and Closure Library

http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/index.en.html

everything works!

Answer (score 1):

This [podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-50/) has some info on how the closure compiler might fit into the IDE. But it was published before closure was released.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in http://plovr.com/, a Closure build tool. It dynamically recompiles JavaScript and Closure Template code.