# Configure Google closure tools with Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, closures

Does anyone know how to integrate Google Closure tools with "Eclipse IDE for Javascript Web Developers" ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these eclipse plugins:

Eclipse Plugin for Closure Templates

Eclipse Plugin for JavaScript with Closure Compiler and Closure Library

http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/index.en.html

everything works!

Answer (score 2):

haven't tried it myself but hope this post help

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287771/integrate-google-closure-compiler-with-eclipse-ide#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287771/integrate-google-closure-compiler-with-eclipse-ide#_=_)